# Remove portion of text from a txt file

Tags: regex, windows, grep, text-files

I need to remove portion of text from a very big text file.
The text file is something like that:

```
Abcdefghijk
LOCK TABLES `core_log` WRITE; <----
(DATA - over 1 Gb of text data)
UNLOCK TABLES;  <----
lmnopqrstuvxyz
```

I need to create a script (Windows or Unix) that remove all content from "LOCK TABLES" to "UNLOCK TABLES;" and preserve rest of file. After the script will run I need to have

```
Abcdefghijk
lmnopqrstuvxyz
```

I can save the extracted data in another file or I can overwrite the same file.
Thanks for help.

Comment: You mean like `LOCK TABLES.*UNLOCK TABLES;\s*` with the `s` modifier?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **GNU** sed:

```
sed -i '/^LOCK TABLES/,/^UNLOCK TABLES/d' file
```

Output to file:

```
Abcdefghijk
lmnopqrstuvxyz
```

Comment: Why only GNU? If I'm not mistaken, your expression is POSIX compatible.

Comment: @randomir: option `-i` is not handled by every sed in the same way.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure about `-i`, but regex address range selection should work everywhere.

Comment: @randomir: I agree with you on that.

Comment: Thanks again Cyrus. Just a little thing. On windows the ' must be replaced with "

Answer (score 2):

This is best done with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^LOCK TABLE/{f=1} /^UNLOCK TABLE/{f=0} f' file
```